# How to create multiple modals in React Router that loads information from the server on click?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a React project where I have a list of users, and I want to implement a functionality similar to Discord, where clicking on a user profile opens a modal next to the profile displaying detailed user information. In Discord, the modal loads data from the server when opened without making any URL changes.

**Desired Outcome:**

1. Clicking on a user link should open a modal with user information.
2. Data for the modal should be fetched from the server only when the modal is opened, not on initial page load.
3. If possible, the URL should not change when the modal is opened.

I have created an example as a description of the UI and logic that I want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hynyqn

I have looked at the [modal example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/modal) given on the react router github repository, and it is not the functionality that I want. It displays the modal content in a general outlet while I need each user profile modal to be seperate and directly beside the corresponding user profile. The modal example also changes the url, which I'd like to avoid in my app if possible.

Comment: React-Router doesn't have much of anything to do with any local data fetching, component state, or rendering modals. You should be able to add some "modal state" to this `Users` component that conditionally toggles the rendering of a modal. Can you [edit] your post to include a [mcve] of the modal logic + UI you are trying to use?

Comment: @DrewReese I have included an example of the UI I am trying to use.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't just render a modal component where you want. There's no intrinsic coupling to routing/navigation here unless you create that yourself like the React-Router docs do. If you don't want that behavior then don't implement that behavior. Links are intended to change the URL, e.g. to navigate to the target URL path, if the intention is to ***not*** navigate then a link is the wrong element/component to use.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement a specific modal with detailed functionalities as you described, there are many aspects to consider. First, you should decide on the type of 'overlay' you want to build.

In my opinion, based on the information you provided, your case is more suited to a 'popover' rather than a modal, because users should be able to interact with the background content.
(of course you can interact with background even if modal's background is screen wrapping, using pointer-events: none;)

check these below.

[image]
[image]

### Popover Position

To place your popover next to a target component, you need to determine the position of the parent tag and base your popover's position on it. You can use 'useRef' or access the element directly by its ID.

### state management

Consider how to manage states between multiple components when implementing modals or popovers. Options include useState, Context API, or external state management libraries - the choice depends on your requirements.

Or you can just adopt some libraries to easily handle state management as I described below.

### rendering popover

Rather than rendering your component directly, you'd better rendering it using react portal in order to avoid potential css collision or z-index problem.

### example

Here is my recent rough  modal implementation.

common modal boilerplate
(component/common/modal.tsx)

```
createPortal(
        <div
          ref={backSection}
          onClick={(e) => {
            if (e.target === backSection.current) close();
          }}
          className="fixed inset-0 z-[1055] h-screen w-full overflow-hidden outline-none"
        >
          <div
            ref={backSection}
            className=" relative flex h-full w-auto translate-y-[-50px] cursor-default items-center transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out min-[576px]:mx-auto min-[576px]:my-7 min-[576px]:max-w-[500px]"
          >
            <div className="min-[576px]:shadow-[0_0.5rem_1rem_rgba(#000, 0.15)] pointer-events-auto relative bottom-40 flex w-full flex-col rounded-md border-[1px]  bg-white bg-clip-padding text-current shadow-lg dark:bg-neutral-600">
              <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center justify-between rounded-t-md  border-neutral-100 border-opacity-100 px-4 pt-4 dark:border-opacity-50">
                <h5 className="text-md font-bold leading-normal text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200">
                  Filter
                </h5>
                <Button2 onClick={close} variant="ghost" size="xs">
                  <XIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
                </Button2>
              </div>
              <div className="relative flex-auto p-4" >
                {children}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>,
       // tag to make a portal(render modals)
        document.getElementById("innerModal")!
      );
```

modal
(component/modal1.tsx)

```
import Modal from "@components/common/Modal";


export default function FictionFilteringModal({
  isOpen,
  close,
}: {
  isOpen: boolean;
  close: () => void;
  exit?: () => void;
}) {


  return (
    <div>
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} close={close}>
       detailed implementation of modal
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

somePage
(page1)

```
<div
        id="innerModal"
        ref={filterButton}
        className={cn(
          buttonVariants({ variant: "outline" }),
          "relative h-full cursor-pointer whitespace-nowrap rounded-2xl p-2 font-bold"
        )}
        onClick={() => {
          overLay.open(({ exit, isOpen, close }) => (
            <FictionFilteringModal
              staticData={staticData}
              close={close}
              isOpen={isOpen}
              exit={exit}
            ></FictionFilteringModal>
          ));
        }}
      >
  <FilteringIcon />
        Filtering
  </div>
```

This is an example of a recent modal implementation using the utility hook library 'useOverlay'(https://slash.page/libraries/react/use-overlay/src/useoverlay.i18n/), which utilizes the Context API. If you use this library, you only need to create a component with the relative position you desire.

I hope this helps, even though my code may not represent the best practice.

Comment: Is this [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) derived? Either way, it doesn't seem very relevant to the OP's question, they aren't requesting help *designing* a modal UI, they just want to trigger rendering it.

Comment: @DrewReese It's not from gpt.... I understand your comment because I correct my grammar issues using gpt. I wrote this answer with much effort because I've been through similar issue and wrote my own post about it recently...
https://velog.io/@sun1301/FDBS-UX%EB%A5%BC-%EC%9C%84%ED%95%9C-%EB%AA%A8%EB%8B%AC-%EB%B0%94%ED%85%80%EC%8B%9C%ED%8A%B8
this is my original post. Anyway, thanks for the feedback.